# Execute script to a particular div only

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Till now we are using Iframe to load HTML and script to show the form to the user.

Now, we want to move from Iframe to DIV, but here we have a problem with script.

Because Iframe is responsible to apply the loaded script to the only iframe, but coming to div script will be loaded into entire HTMLDocument.

Is There any way that loaded script can be applied to that specific DIV only?

Thanks.

Comment: please, show your code so Ican help you

Comment: @Matheus please refer to the pen.  https://codepen.io/AbdulRahman575/pen/jePVwY we will be having multiple iframes loaded with javascript functions and we are looking to move from Iframe to DIV.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `<iframe></frame>` to `<div></div>` after this, you have this way to do this for your CSS(to a certain div):

```
#projectName{
style:value;
}

#divAnnounce{

}
```

The # targets things with ID's if you use a . before it will target the class names,

You can also use both if you need to get specific such as

```
#idname.classname{

}
```

If you have another div inside of the divAnnounce you can do

```
#divAnnounce #yournewdiv{

}
```

OR

```
#divAnnounce div{

}
```

OR

```
#newdivid{

}
```

Notice the space inbetween the two targets saying that they are a parent and child.

For your javascript I don't know with you are using plain javascript or jQuery

if it is jQuery then you can use jQuery [noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). Create separate aliases to use jQuery for example to div1 & div2

Simple Example:

```
    <script>
        var div1Alias = $.noConflict();
        var div2Alias = div1Alias.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             alert(div1Alias( "#div1" ).html());
             alert(div2Alias( "#div2" ).html());
        });
    </script>
```

Try to do this changes in your code and let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but we need to do this way. 
refer to https://codepen.io/AbdulRahman575/pen/VEepgd?editors=1000 
Each Div is going to have its script and that script is going to responsible for that particular div only. The function names in script and variables names are going to same/different in an unhandled way.